# find and replace in a text file using sed

Tags: replace, sed, find

I am new to sed.

I have a text file and I want to replace the occurrence of this string:

```
allow ^127\.0\.0\.1$
```

with this string:

```
allow ^107\.21\.206\.35$
```

the code I used was the following:

```
sed 's/allow ^127\.0\.0\.1$/allow ^107\.21\.206\.35$/g' test.txt
```

However, id did not work.  What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to make the change to the file itself? If so, you'll need the `-i` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape not only the `\` (with another backslash) but also the `.` (Regular Expressions treat `.` as "match any single character"). The `^` and `$` characters are also reserved in Regular Expressions.

```
$ echo "allow ^127\.0\.0\.1$" > /tmp/test
$ cat /tmp/test
allow ^127\.0\.0\.1$
$ sed 's/allow \^127\\\.0\\\.0\\\.1\$/allow ^107\\.21\\.206\\.35$/g' -i /tmp/test
$ cat /tmp/test
allow ^107.21.206.35$
```

In the replace string, the `\` should be escaped otherwise the single `\` will escape the `.` next to it.

Comment: @potong good point, in the above example it's not necessary to escape the first `^` in sed's regex. However `^` is also the negation operator in a set, and should be escaped in that context too.

Answer (score 1):

You must escape '^' and '$':

```
$ sed 's/allow \^127\.0\.0\.1\$/allow \^107\.21\.206\.35\$/g' test.txt
```

Unescaped, the '^' matches the beginning of the line, and '$' matches the end of line.  In order to match the character exactly, they must be escaped with '\'.  Most implementation of sed use basic regular expressions in which the following characters must be escaped to match literally:
`^.[$()|*+?{\`

Comment: @Monty: I did not notice that you had literal '\' in your input text.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo 'allow ^127\.0\.0\.1$' | 
sed 's/allow ^127\\.0\\.0\\.1\$/allow ^107\\.21\\.206\\.35$/'
allow ^107\.21\.206\.35$
```

The `^` and `$` only need to be escaped in the match part of the substitution command if they are at the front and back of a string respectively. The `\` needs to be escaped in both the match and the replacement.